# Can I somehow convert Binding<String> to String?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to call a function that looks like this

```
func customTextField(placeholder: String, text: Binding<String>) -> some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading){
            if text.isEmpty{
                VStack {
                    Text(placeholder)
                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                        .fontWeight(.regular)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.5803921568627451, green: 0.5803921568627451, blue: 0.5803921568627451))
                        .padding()
                    
                    if placeholder == "Your message type here..."{
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
            
            TextField("", text: text)
                .font(.system(size: 14))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding()
            
        }
        .frame(height: placeholder == "Your message type here..." ? 170 : 54)
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).stroke(text.isEmpty ? Color.clear : Color("orange")))
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(16)
    }
```

But as `text` is a `Binding<String>` I can't use `.isEmpty()` on it. I don't want to create another struct view for it.
What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You simply need to call `wrappedValue` on a `Binding` to access its underlying value, there's no need for any type conversion.

So do

```
text.wrappedValue.isEmpty
```

instead of

```
text.isEmpty
```